# domain of composition of continuous functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions from $R^2$ to $R^2$.

$f$ and $g$ both have open domains. That is, $f$ and $g$ are both defined on open sets of $\mathbf{R}^2$.

Is it true that the domain of $f(g)$ is also open?

By domain of $f(g)$, I mean the set of all $x \in \mathbf{R}^2$ such that $f(g(x))$ is well defined.

How to prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: In fact, we have more conditions than we need. It suffices that $g$ is continuous and that $\operatorname{dom}(f),\operatorname{dom}(g)$ are open, so that $$\begin{align}\operatorname{dom}(f\circ g) &= \{x\in\Bbb R:x\in\operatorname{dom}(g)\text{ and }g(x)\in\operatorname{dom}(f)\\ &= \{x\in\operatorname{dom}(g):g(x)\in\operatorname{dom}(f)\}\\ &= g^{-1}[\operatorname{dom}(f)]\end{align}$$ is relatively open in $\operatorname{dom}(g)$ as the preimage of an open set under a continuous function, and so open in $\Bbb R^2$ since $\operatorname{dom}(g)$ is open.

Now, if we want $f\circ g$ to be continuous, then we will in general need $f$ to be continuous, as well.

Comment: It suffices that g is continuous and that dom(f) is open---counterexample: $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$, so f(g) is defined on a closed but not open set.

Comment: @kedrigern: Not quite. We can say that $\operatorname{dom}(g)$ is open *in itself* by that reasoning, but not necessarily open in $\Bbb R^2.$ For example, let $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ denote the standard Euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^2,$ let $A=\{x\in\Bbb R^2:\lVert x\rVert\ge 1\},$ and define $g:A\to\Bbb R^2$ by $g(x)=\frac1{\lVert x\rVert}x.$ This is continuous, but the given domain is not open in $\Bbb R$. And now that I say that, that means that my own reasoning is faulty, as well. Let me think on it, and I'll fix my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Cameron: Right, I just realized that. $\operatorname{dom}(g)$ is open in itself not generally in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @kedrigern: I have fixed my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Yes, $\operatorname{dom}(f\circ g)$ is open in $\operatorname{dom}(g)$ so is of the form $\operatorname{dom}(g)\cap X$ where $X\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is open and therefore is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as well.

Comment: @noot: Thank you for pointing that out! My answer should be correct now. Apologies for the earlier mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of $f(g)$ is $g^{-1}[\operatorname{dom} f]$ which is open as a continuous pre-image of an open set.

Comment: do you need the condition that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: I don't think we need it.

Comment: It suffices that g is continuous and that dom(f) is open---counterexample: $f(x)=x, g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ so f(g) is defined on a closed but not open set.